# I created this dropdown box but the items are not getting selected. I am leaving my code here, can anyone help me out?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have attached the codes, please help me with how to get it running.
I coded the dropdown box, everything is fine but I guess there is some problem with javascript as the options are not getting selected. I coded the HTML, added CSS, but the javascript part is creating a problem. I have attached a code snippet here, please check once and reply. Thank You...

```js
const select = document.querySelector(".select");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".dropdown-list");

const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-list_item");

.select.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
})

optionsList.forEach( o =>{
  o.addEventListener("click",() =>{
    select.innerHTML= o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown{
  width: 20rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20%;
  color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover  .dropdown-list {
  opacity: 10;
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-select{
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size:  1.6 rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-list{
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top:110%;
  left: 29%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear;
}

.dropdown-list_item{
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="textbox">
      <div id="content">
        <h1 class="form">COMPLAINT TYPE</h1>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-select">
    <span class="select">Selected Type</span>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
      <div class="dropdown-list_item">Drainage System Issue</div>
      <div class="dropdown-list_item">Garbage Collection</div>
      <div class="dropdown-list_item">Public Place Cleanliness</div>
      <div class="dropdown-list_item">Sweeping Of Roads</div>
      <div class="dropdown-list_item">Others</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There is an error in your javascript according to the snippet: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'"`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this even related to CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading `.` before the `select.addEventListener(...` was likely a typo caused by the copy/paste? However the use of `o.querySelector("label").innerHTML` was throwing an error as there is no `label` element in the above HTML. If you omit that and simply use `select.innerHTML= o.innerHTML;` it does what I think you wanted?

```js
const select = document.querySelector(".select");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".dropdown-list");

const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-list_item");

select.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
})

optionsList.forEach( o =>{
  o.addEventListener("click",() =>{
    select.innerHTML= o.innerHTML;
    optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown{
  width: 20rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20%;
  color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover  .dropdown-list {
  opacity: 10;
  visibility: visible;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.dropdown-select{
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size:  1.6 rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-list{
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top:110%;
  left: 29%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear, visibility 0.2s linear;
}

.dropdown-list_item{
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="textbox">
        <div id="content">
            <h1 class="form">COMPLAINT TYPE</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-select">
                <span class="select">Selected Type</span>
                <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-list">
                <div class="dropdown-list_item">Drainage System Issue</div>
                <div class="dropdown-list_item">Garbage Collection</div>
                <div class="dropdown-list_item">Public Place Cleanliness</div>
                <div class="dropdown-list_item">Sweeping Of Roads</div>
                <div class="dropdown-list_item">Others</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```